# Raise positive VB style error codes via COM interop from C#

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, vb6, com-interop

I have a base library created in VB6 that exposes a standard COM interface that is used in a number of applications.
This also exposed a number of error code constants, used with `Err.Raise` to indicate certain conditions.

```
Public Enum IOErrors
  IOErrorBase = 45000
  IOErrorConnectionFailed
  IOErrorAuthFailed
  IOErrorNotConnected
  IOErrorInvalidPortDirection
  IOErrorGettingValue
  IOErrorNoValueYet
End Enum
```

Come on 10 years and we're creating C# objects implementing the same set of interfaces and want to throw exceptions in a way that the calling application will recognise them.

I can only find two relevant classes, `Win32Exception` and `COMException`.

Throwing `Win32Exception((int)IOErrors.IOErrorConnectionFailed, "Connect failed")` passes the message back correctly but the error code is ignored and `Err.Number` is `&H80004005`.

Throwing `COMException("Connect failed", IOErrors.IOErrorConnectionFailed)` results in no error being picked up in the calling application, presumably because the error code is not an `HRESULT` and is positive, meaning success.

TL;DR
How can I throw an exception from C# such that COM interop will translate it into one of the recognised (positive) error codes above?

Comment: Related question: [How to return positive error code from ATL to VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16448222/588306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "positive" VB style error numbers are translated to `HRESULT`s with a "FAILURE" severity and a facility of `FACILITY_CONTROL`/`0xA`, i.e. `0x800AAFC9`.

You can get a suitable `HRESULT` using:

```
int HResult = (int)(0x800A0000 | (int)errorCode);
```

This can then be raised back to the calling process using a plain `COMException`, or by throwing your own subclass of `COMException`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Exception that returns an ICIO error wrapped in an exception.
/// </summary>
internal class ICIOErrorException : COMException {
    internal ICIOErrorException(ICIO.IOErrors errorCode, string message)
        : base(message) {
        this.HResult = (int)(0x800A0000 | (int)errorCode);
    }
}
```